# Quota error using google-map-react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Using google-map-react I'm getting error `You have exceeded your request quota for this API. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors`

I added billing because of the new google api policy, and I tried opening a new api account which has billing built in. Still get the same error.

My app has been working for a year. Just stopped Aug 6 '18.

Does google-map-react need updating? Abandon it for now?

Comment: Does this occur for all your users, or just you as a developer? It looks like your personal quota has been exceeded, not the entire API quota.

Comment: Just for me. The quota is unlimited and resets every day at midnight I think. Right?

Comment: Also I opened a new API instance. Doesn't that start over at zero? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Correction - Users are getting the same error.

Comment: Very frustrating. I saw a very similar question a few days back, but we couldn't figure out what it was.